# How to connect SoC modules with http request

Tags: swift, module, get, soc

I have a device. The device belongs to Arylic company. I'm connecting to the socket inside this:

```
GET <http://192.168.10.1/httpapi.asp?command=%7Bcommand%7D>
```

I am trying to connect. I opened local network permissions or tried almost all variations but could not connect to this device. How can I do it?

Device Modules Doc: https://developer.arylic.com/httpapi/#http-api

```swift
struct APInfo: Decodable {
    let auth: String
    let bssid: String
    let channel: Int
    let extch: String
    let rssi: Int
    let ssid: String
}

struct APListResponse: Decodable {
    let res: Int
    let aplist: [APInfo]
}

func performAPListRequest() async throws -> APListResponse {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://4.6.327252.26/httpapi.asp?command=wlanGetApListEx") else {
        throw URLError(.badURL)
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.timeoutInterval = 30
    
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200..<300).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
        throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
    }
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let result = try decoder.decode(APListResponse.self, from: data)
    return result
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(viewModel.apList, id: \.bssid) { ap in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("SSID: \(ap.ssid)")
                    Text("BSSID: \(ap.bssid)")
                    Text("Channel: \(ap.channel)")
                    Text("RSSI: \(ap.rssi)")
                }
                .onAppear {
                    print("SSID: \(ap.ssid)")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button("Fetch AP List") {
                Task {
                    try? await viewModel.fetchAPList()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var apList: [APInfo] = []
    
    func fetchAPList() async throws {
        do {
            let response = try await performAPListRequest()
            self.apList = response.aplist
        } catch {
            // Handle error here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why ignore any possible errors?

Comment: `// Handle error here` -> `print("Error: \(error)")`, does this print something?